# SharePoint Designer support for SharePoint Online sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, flow

Does Microsoft provide support for SharePoint Designer to use in SharePoint Online sites?

We have multiple sites in SharePoint Online environment that need workflow. What would be the best approach -- to use Flow or to use Designer?

Answer (score 4):

Yes SharePoint Online sites can be opened using SharePoint Designer 2013.

You can download the SharePoint Designer 2013 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35491)

Yes, it is possible to create workflows in SharePoint designer for SP Online sites.

Difficult to tell which approach is the best, but MSFlow are to stay here and the extended support to SP Designer 2013 is going to be till 2026.

Hence it is recommended to use MSFlow. Please take decision as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: @rajshekhar sheelvant thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides support for SharePoint designer to use in SharePoint online sites.You can using SharePoint Designer to create workflow in SharePoint online. 
But SharePoint Designer 2013 will not be supported beyond 2026.

SharePoint Designer workflow is only confined to SharePoint while Microsoft Flow has the ability to interface with other applications.

But Microsoft Flow is not the direct replacement for SharePoint Workflows. Microsoft Flow is the evolution of business process management allowing you to build elegant solutions which have the ability to orchestrate data across the various line of business applications leveraging “clicks” and not code.

Reference:

https://collab365.community/sharepoint-designer-workflow-vs-microsoft-flow/